# UITableViewCell is 1px shorter in didSelectRowAtIndexPath than cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UITableViewCell that I create in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. In that method I call:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
NSLog(@"Cell height: %f", cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
```

This gives me a return value of `44.000000`.

Then in my `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, I call:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
NSLog(@"Cell height: %f", cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
```

And this gives me a return value of `43.000000`. Aren't they the same cell? What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would chock this one up to Apple's behind-the-scenes highlighting magic.

Comment: Any idea how to get it to display right? Besides just adding 1 to the second height? Seems a bit hackish to me.

Comment: Does it not display right?  Can you visually see the cell shrink?

Comment: No, but I have a UIImageView (a checkbox) in there using CGRectOffset() for placement. I calculate the height of the frame so that I can position it, then change the image when the row is selected. But when the new image comes up it moves itself up 1 pixel. I can fix this just by adding a pixel, but it just seems hackish. Maybe I'm just being too uptight.

Comment: It does seem hackish, but sometimes you just have to be hackish I guess.  Sorry for the lame answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the separator. Have you looked into that?